# Rails rendering text in view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a custom action and view for it. Where I suggest to get a collection from my action and show it by `each`. This is my view:

```
=  @games.each do |g|
.well
    %h2= link_to g.name, game_path(g)
    = link_to (image_tag g.image.url(:medium), class: 'img-responsive'), game_path(g)
```

This is my action:

```
def unproved_games
  @games = Game.where(status: false)
end
```

Its render good, but in the end i got this on my page:
[image: trash]

How can I Fix it?

Comment: Just remove a leading equal sign `=` in front of `@games.each`.

Comment: change = to - in front of @games.each

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` markup in HAML means to create some output on the page (similar to `<%= %>` in ERB. `each` method returns a collection, it was called on. That's why on your page you see an output that is similar to `@games.to_s`. Just replace your very first `=` with `-` and it will make no output to the page. And also I've made some additional refactoring of your code:

```
- @games.each do |g|
  .well
    %h2= link_to g.name, g
    = link_to g do
      = image_tag g.image.url(:medium), class: 'img-responsive')
```

Comment: @Val-Lee Does my answer helped you? It would be very cool if you stay in touch with people who spent their time to help you until your question is resolved

Comment: @AntonTkechov, thanks! Ur answer is absolutely true and helpful, but I solved my problem in comments under my post and I dont know how to mark it as solved. Sorry, I am newbie at stack